# Show that PA can prove the pigeon-hole principle

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, peano-axioms

So the following exercise is from Richard Kaye's Book exercise 5.12 (Chapter 5)

The pigeon-hole principle is the scheme:

For any formula, $\psi$, in the language of arithmetics,

$\forall s\ ((\forall x<s+1, \exists e<s\ \psi(x,e)) \rightarrow\ \exists x, r < s+1, \exists e<s (x \neq r\  \wedge\psi(x,e) \wedge\psi(r,e)))$

Show that PA can prove (every instances) of the statement.

This statement is so intuitively true, but I'm having some trouble proving it and I dont quite understand the hints given in the book.

Any help or insights is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if the pigeon-hole principle is confined to PA. Or number theory in general. Is there not some purely set-theoretic formulation that makes no reference to numbers at all?

Comment: If you are interested, there is apparently such a non-numeric version of the pigeonhole principle, but it uses set theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is trickier than it looks at first. If you try to prove it directly by induction on $s$ you run into the problem that you'll need the induction hypothesis for a *different* $\psi$ -- which is not allowed because that's a different induction.

I think you need to go "the long way around" and start by replacing the $\psi$ with something you can quantify over, such as [Gödel's $\beta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_%CE%B2_function):
$$ \forall s,b,c: \bigl( \forall x<s+1: (\beta(b,c,x)<s ) \to \exists x,r<s+1: (x\ne r \land \beta(b,c,x) = \beta(b,c,r)) \bigr) $$
Since $\beta$ is a single function whose formula is the same no matter the *values* of $b$ and $c$, you can prove *this* by induction on $s$.

Along the way you need a number of lemmas about manipulating $\beta$-encoded sequences. If you already have those lemmas in your toolbox the going is not too bad; otherwise there's a lot of work to do, which will include proving some form of the Chinese Remainder Theorem along the way.

Finally, prove as a metatheorem that for every $\psi$ you can derive
$$ \forall s: (\forall x<s+1\,\exists e<s : \psi(x,e)) \to \exists b,c\, \forall x<s+1 : \bigl( (\beta(b,c,x)<s \land \psi(x,\beta(b,c,x)) \bigr) $$
which you can then combine with the above to get the formula you're after.

Comment: For those who don't have the book at hand, this is essentially the method that Kaye suggests. Essentially, in PA we can define codes for functions from finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{N}$. So, if the pigeonhole principle failed, we would be able to show that for some $s$ there is a code for an injective function from $[s+1]$ to $[s]$. Now, Kaye suggests, consider the least $s$ for which there is such a coded function, and follow the usual proof of the pigeonhole principle. The relation to this answer is that the $\beta$ function is one way to construct these codes.

Comment: I must be missing something obvious, but could you elaborate abit more on the last step, where you said 'combine' with the above'. Thank you so much

Comment: The last part is saying that we can use the assumption on $\psi$ to code a finite function (via $b,c$) that is an injection from $\{0, \ldots, s\}$ to $\{0, \ldots, s-1\}$. Then the previous part shows there cannot be a code for a function like that. @some1fromhell

Answer (score 3):

Since the proof suggested by Kaye is sketched in another answer, I'll mention a more high powered way to prove this. Because the second-order system $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ is conservative over PA for sentences in the language of PA, we can just prove the statement in $\mathsf{ACA}_0$.  This is easier because we can work directly with functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, and can form any function that is arithmetically definable.

First, we can prove in $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ that if $f$ is any injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ then, for all $s$, $f([s+1]) \not \subseteq [s]$.  This uses the ordinary proof of the pigeonhole principle.

Then we show that if any of the statements Kaye is considering were to fail, we could use this to construct a injection that contradicts the previous claim. In particular, if the statement fails at $s$, we would let $f(i) = (\mu j \leq s) \psi(i,j)$ for $i \leq s+1$ and $f(i) = i$ for $i > s+1$, which is arithmetically definable.